# Passing JavaScript to Closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning how to actually use JavaScript. I've run into a situation where I'm getting an error. The error is: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.flagged')`. I've narrowed down my code to where its happening. My code looks like this:

```
var flagged = false;
var intervals = [];

return {
  flagged: flagged,
  intervals: intervals,

  createInterval : function (options) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if (this.throwsError) {
      defer.reject('There was an error creating the interval.');
    } else {
      this.intervals.push(
        $interval(function() {
          console.log('here 1');
          console.log(this.flagged); 
        },
        1000
      ));
    }
  }
};
```

The error gets thrown at the: `console.log(this.flagged);` I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that "`this`" isn't visible. Yet, if "`this`" isn't visible, I'm not sure how to get the value for `flagged`. Can someone please explain to me what I need to do to get the value for `flagged`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `this` inside `$interval` it won't be pointing to your original object, however, you can do this:

```
var flagged = false;
var intervals = [];

return {
  flagged: flagged,
  intervals: intervals,

  createInterval : function (options) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
        self = this;
    if (this.throwsError) {
      defer.reject('There was an error creating the interval.');
    } else {
      this.intervals.push(
        $interval(function() {
          console.log('here 1');
          console.log(self.flagged); 
        },
        1000
      ));
    }
  }
};
```

notice `var self = this;`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript,

```
var flagged
```

will be a scoped variable, i think what you need here is a global scope variable for that, simply remove var from behind it.

```
flagged = false;
```

that should do the trick.